# EF core set default OrderBy to a List property in the parent entity

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I need an attribute or a fluent method to set the default OrderBy to a property to avoid to have to add the OrderBy clause each time I use an Include.

```cs
public class ItemsGroup : BaseEntity
    {
        public virtual List<ItemDefinition> ItemDefinitions { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

```cs
public class ItemDefinition: BaseEntity
    {
        ...
        public int Position { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to add an attribute like that

```cs
[DefaultOrderBy(nameof(ItemDefinition.Position), Sorting.Asc)]
public virtual List<ItemDefinition> ItemDefinitions { get; set; }
```

or something like that :

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ItemsGroup>().Property(ig => ig.ItemDefinitions).DefaultOrderBy(id => id.Position, Sorting.Asc);
```

I saw some interesting workaround like [this](https://dotnetfalcon.com/stackoverflow-adventures-specifying-default-sort-order-in-ef-using-query-interceptors/) for EF with interceptors and visitors but I can't reproduce it with EF core.

Is there a way to do something like that with EF core?

Comment: There's no such thing. EF Core generates SQL queries, it doesn't access the database directly. A SQL query has no implied order unless `ORDER BY` is used.

Comment: What is exactly what you want to achieve ? Enumerating values in a given order (application will do the sorting) or automatically add `ORDER BY` in the query (RDBMS will do the sorting) ?

Comment: @ArwynFr I have a big application with many complexe queries and includes/load and these objects can be nested or used in other entities too. I need to "inject" the ORDER BY clause in some entities list to avoir to change hundred of queries and make it possible to change it in one time if the ordering must be changed. if I just insert items, it's not a problem as EF core will return the list in the good order but if I reorder the list, I lose the correct positions. as well, I need to be able to set different ordering for some other entites (by date, in another parent entity)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the link I provided uses interceptor and visitors and seems to do what I need, but it's for EF and not EF core. I tried to adapt it but I couldn't find a way to do it

Comment: Query interceptors and global filters exist in EF Core as well. No visitors are needed. *Why do you want them though?*. Sorting isn't free. Without an index to accelerate it, an ORDER BY can easily end up storing all results in a temporary database and sorting the data in a second pass.

Comment: as well, the Position property is set by a drag'n'drop system, I don't need to set the position value dynamically, I already have the indexes, I just need to define a default ORDER BY for the property.

Comment: If you google for `EF Core Query interceptors` the first result is [Interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) in the docs. Your data model isn't built to serve only a single form though. If a specific form wants to display data in a certain order, then that form should use an explicit `OrderBy` instead of forcing an expensive `ORDER BY` on every other query

Answer (score 0):

Am not aware that you can do this directly.

Perhaps an extension method:

```
public static IList<ItemDefinition> SortedByPosition(this IList<ItemDefinition> list)
{
    return list.OrderBy(i => i.Position);
}
```

Use:

```
foreach (var ItemDefinition in myDefinitionList.SortedByPosition())
{
    // use itemDefinition
}
```

Or, if you want them sorted at source, the following should work:

```
public class ItemsGroup
{
    [NotMapped]
    private IList<ItemDefinitions> _itemDefinitions;

    public IList<ItemDefinitions> ItemDefinitions
    {
        get => _itemDefinitions;
        set
        {
            _itemDefinitions = value.OrderBy(i => i.Position);
        }
    }
}
```

Then they're sorted from the get go.

Comment: None of these methods uses EF Core. All of these work on already loaded arrays or lists. Instead of ordering the data every time the property is accessed it would be better to sort them only once, when the property is set. Or even better, when the data is loaded

Comment: The second option in my answer will result in only being sorted once.

Comment: And none of those options imposes a default sort order. It orders the data only once it's loaded. The real problem though is that `ItemDefinitions` is `virtual`, something typically used with *lazy* loading. If the poster tries to use lazy loading, the setter will be overriden. And yet, the poster talks about `Include` which imposes eager loading